# Does receiving new hire paper work and a job offer letter mean I got the job?

Tags: communication, united-states

I recently took a drug test.

The next day I received an email that contained new hire paper work and a job offer letter.

I am wondering - does this mean that I got the job?

Comment: Did you not get a single call or even email from someone at the company informing you that they'd be offering you a job? In Europe job offers are usually contracts that are legally binding and are not sent lightly but you have no such protection in the US and a letter sent by mistake could easily be pulled later.

Answer (score 10):

Nicole, read the job offer letter carefully.  In many jurisdictions it is common for the company to leave exit options for themselves if new information arises or the information changes.  Nothing is official until all of the paperwork is done, so while this doesn't mean you have a job yet you have the job offer and the company expects to hire you.

But, in the usual sense, if you have a "new hire" packet then the company regards you as a person who is in the process of joining.

Comment: Ok thank you, also it told me when I would be starting but I didn't fill out any tax forms. Just a little confused.

Comment: If you are in the US, the I-9 (employment eligibility) and W-4 (tax withholding) might be filled out on your first day.

Comment: Ok. Yes in the US. You were definitely a big help. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jason is right on the money.  Be sure to bring in your state-issued ID (most commonly a drivers license) and your social security card.  Your employer will likely want to see both.

Answer (score 0):

> The next day I received a email that was new hire paper work and a job
>   offer letter. Wondering does this mean i got the job.

Usually a "job offer letter" means that they are *offering* you the job. If the offer has no conditions, then you will have the job once you accept.

Read it, and see what it says and you'll have your answer. Sometimes the wording will say "pending a successful drug test" or such. In that case, the offer is *conditional* and you don't have the job yet.